# How To Get Views Argument as a Like / Contains Instead of Equals

Tags: 6, views

I have a view that I need to filter using the logic Field_a Contains url_argument_1. Or in SQL Field_a LIKE '%url_argument_1%'. The problem I am having is only filters let me use the "Contains" operator and only Arguments let me access url_argument_1. How can I combine them?

Just for clarity url_argument_1 is Argument #1 that is passed into the view from the URL. Also, if at all possible I want to avoid writing a custom module. I prefer to do this via the views interface.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solution would be to filter results by argument value. Unfortunately, this doesn't seem to be doable in Views at the moment. Not via the Views interface, anyway.

However, by altering **exposed** filter form to set current argument value as filter default value, users have managed to get such functionality to work: http://drupal.org/node/360780

I don't know what state it is in, but you may want to have a look at this module, which is supposed to do just that -- enable using argument placeholders (%1, %2) as filter values: http://drupal.org/sandbox/itangalo/1086472 (git only)